# Google Forms - App script won't iterate through all form fields

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have made a Google Form and `onSubmit` an app script will run iterating through all form questions and answers however **some** questions, when the corresponding answer is left empty, are not listed/available in the iteration. Nevertheless, many questions whose answer is empty, are "listed" in the iteration.

`function onSubmit(e) {
      var items = e.response.getItemResponses();
      var emailBody = '';
      for (i in items){
        // the follwoing will not iterate all questions
        emailBody+= "<br/>"+ items[i].getItem().getTitle()+": "+items[i].getResponse();
      }
      ......... other code follows .....
    }`

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it! Items being left out from the list are checkboxes with no answer... from the Google documentation:

> **getItemResponses()** Gets all item responses contained in a form response, in the same order that the items appear in the form. If the form response does not contain a response for a given TextItem, DateItem, TimeItem, or ParagraphTextItem, the ItemResponse returned for that item will have an empty string as the response. If the form response omits a response for any other item type, this method excludes that item from its returned array.